# concat two dataframes by index

Tags: python, pandas

I've two dataframes and I want to merge/add/concat them
example

```
>>> df
    name   name1   name2  v1  v2  v3
0   test   test1   test2   5  10  15
1  test1  test11  test21   6  11  16

>>> df2
    name   name1   name2  v1  v2  v3
0   test   test1   test2   7  12  18
1  test2  test15  test25   3   5   1
```

I can concat them by multiindex, like

```
>>> pd.concat([df, df2]).groupby(['name', 'name1', 'name2'])['v1', 'v2', 'v3'].sum()
                     v1  v2  v3
name  name1  name2             
test  test1  test2   12  22  33
test1 test11 test21   6  11  16
test2 test15 test25   3   5   1
```

or set multiindex for each df and add, like

```
>>> df.set_index(['name', 'name1', 'name2']).add(df2.set_index(['name', 'name1', 'name2']), fill_value=0)
                     v1  v2  v3
name  name1  name2             
test  test1  test2   12  22  33
test1 test11 test21   6  11  16
test2 test15 test25   3   5   1
```

My question is, can I add them by index 'name', sum v1, v2, v3 and just copy name1 and name2 from 'name', because in my dataframes if nameX equal nameY, then name1X and name1Y equals, same as name2X and name2Y.
Dataframes too large so I want avoid multiindex

alghorithm: concat df and df2, groupby by name, sum v1, v2, v3 and add name1 and name2 from df/df2 where exists

Thanks in advance!

commands for create test data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'name1', 'name2', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3'])
df = df.append({'name': 'test', 'name1': 'test1', 'name2': 'test2', 'v1': 5, 'v2': 10, 'v3': 15}, ignore_index=True)
df = df.append({'name': 'test1', 'name1': 'test11', 'name2': 'test21', 'v1': 6, 'v2': 11, 'v3': 16}, ignore_index=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name', 'name1', 'name2', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3'])
df2 = df2.append({'name': 'test', 'name1': 'test1', 'name2': 'test2', 'v1': 7, 'v2': 12, 'v3': 18}, ignore_index=True)
df2 = df2.append({'name': 'test2', 'name1': 'test15', 'name2': 'test25', 'v1': 3, 'v2': 5, 'v3': 1}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can create a loop to iterate through each value that compares, and if true, puts the items together.

> df = [...] df2 = [...]
>
> for key in df  for df in range(len(df)):
>       if df[key] == df2[key]:
>           #concatenate the values here
>           return values   # then return them